# How to implement Android web-services using Core php?

Tags: php, android, web-services

Apologise for the silly question in advance.
I have learned php to do web-services on Android. I can perform post and get request using php.

I have also configured postman chrome api and could be able check how request comes.

Now I am stuck up in how I can perform login, registration web-services for android app using core php?

Any suggestion, reference link, articles will be mush appreciated.

Even just basic steps, how can be done in flow can help me a lot to explore by myself.

Comment: try this https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-rest-api-for-android/

https://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Good enough to give a nice start.

The concept would remain same, it's basically the client side that can get changed. You can call the same services using java or php or android.

Authentication can be done by a number of techniques. You can use token based mechanism, encryption with salt, etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: nice comment @Danyal Sandeelo